# Dimension of a closed linear subspace of a separable Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal, separable-spaces, projection

> Given a separable Hilbert space $(X,(\cdot,\cdot))$, a closed linear
>   subspace $V\subset X$ and an orthonormal basis $\{e_i\ |\
>  i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for $X$, show that \begin{equation}
>      \dim V = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \|Pe_i\|^2, \end{equation}
>
> where $\|\cdot\|: X \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \sqrt{(x,x)}$ and $P$
>   is the projection of $X$ onto $V$.

The steps I have taken:

1. I have shown that for all elements $x_1,x_2 \in X$, it holds that 
   $(Px_1,x_2) = (x_1, Px_2)$.
2. If $\{v_i\ |\ i \in I \subset \mathbb{N}\}$ is a basis for $V$ with $|v_i|=1$ for each 
   $i$, then
   \begin{equation}
   \dim V = \sum_{i\in I}\|v_i\|^2.
   \end{equation}
3. By the fact that $X$ is separable and that $\{e_i\ |\ i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $X$, there exists a countable dense subsets $E\in X$ such that
   \begin{equation}
   \overline{\text{span}}\ E = X = \overline{\text{span}}\ \{e_i\ |\ i\in\mathbb{N}\}.
   \end{equation}

From this point, I don't know how to connect this to obtain a proof. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would change the basis to $\{v_i\}\cup\{w_i\}$ where the $v_i$ are a basis for $V$ and the $w_i$ are a basis for the orthogonal complement. Then it's just a question of whether $V$ is finite dimensional or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(f_j)_{j \in J}$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$, with $\dim V = \operatorname{card} J$, then the orthogonal projection $P : X \to V$ is given by

$$Px = \sum_{j \in J} \langle x, f_j\rangle f_j$$

Then in particular $$Pe_i = \sum_{j \in J} \langle e_i, f_j\rangle f_j \implies \|Pe_i\|^2 = \sum_{j\in J} \left|\langle e_i, f_j\rangle \right|^2$$

So we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \|Pe_i\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j\in J} \left|\langle e_i, f_j\rangle \right|^2 = \sum_{j \in J} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left|\langle e_i, f_j\rangle \right|^2 \stackrel{\text{Parseval}}{=} \sum_{j \in J} \|f_j\|^2 = \sum_{j \in J} 1 = \operatorname{card} J = \dim V$$

We can exchange the sums because $\left|\langle e_i, f_j\rangle \right|^2 \ge 0$.

Comment: So how do we know that an orthonormal basis for $V$ exists?

Comment: @User2935032946 A separable inner product space $X$ always has an orthonormal basis: if $(x_n)_n$ is a countable dense subset of $X$, then it can be inductively reduced to a linearly independent dense subset, and then you can apply Gram-Schmidt to it to obtain an ONB. $V$ is a subspace of $X$ so it is also a separable inner product space.

Comment: Btw. I assumed that $\dim V$ refers to the orthonormal dimension, i.e. the cardinality of the largest orthonormal subset of $V$ (and not the algebraic dimension, the cardinality of the largest linearly independent subset of $V$).